# What's the difference between these two confidence intervals?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, chi-squared-distribution

I have this following problem on my Stats problem set:

[image]

I was fully able to answer every item except item e). In item d), I used the fact that the Wald statistic converges in distribution to a chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom.

As far as I am concerned, I should use the exact same approximation for item e), except that I cannot write a confidence interval for $\theta_{0}$ since the information matrix also depends on $\theta_{0}$ and therefore I cannot "invert the test". So, I would end up with a confidence interval of the right confidence level for $I(\theta_{0})(\hat{\theta}_{n} - \theta_{0})$ but not for the parameter itself.

I don't know if this was the catch of this exercise but I would like to know if I'm on the right path and if there's something more I can say about item e).